# Vba code to count no consecutive 1s

Tags: vba, excel

In excel I have a bunch of columns that are made up of a sequence of 1s and 0s. For each column I am looking to count the number of times that there are 4 or more 1s consecutive 1s in that column. I believe that a piece of vba code would be the easiest way to do this?

Example:

```
0
1
1
1
1
0
1
1
1
1
1
0
```

0

The count here would be 2.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: loop through the data and look at the ones that are NOT `1` and check if the rows are far enough apart to have at least 4 in them.

Answer (score 1):

use this function:

```
    Function Count1s(rng As Range) As Long
Dim rArr() As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim t As Long
Dim n As Long
t = 0
rArr = rng.Value

For i = 1 To UBound(rArr, 1)
    If rArr(i, 1) <> 1 Then
        If t + 4 <= i Then
            n = n + 1
        End If
        t = i
    End If
Next i
Count1s = n
End Function
```

You would call it as a regular formula:

```
=Count1s(A1:A12)
```

[image]